# How can I have permanent DNS name for Elastic Beanstalk DOCKER environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

So since each EB env version update is recreating ec2 instance, is there some tricky way to catch this newly created ec2 instance public ip/dns name and keep it behind permanent Route 53 alias?

Ofc (as far as I use boto api) I can search newly created instance by name, get address, set it to R53 record but maybe exist other built-in way to handle **exactly docker** based Beanstalk environment DNS?

Thanks

UPD.: Or deployed once ec2 instance keep the same parameters while I not change beanstalk env. VPC params related with instance tier etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your EB domain name, you can associate your R53 with your EB, no your IP Address and no your EC2 Domain... In your R53 recorset select alias YES and select your Elastic Beanstalk instance.. The R53 will be changing the ip address is you rebuild your Elastic Beanstalk Environment. Ever keep the Environment, you can update, increase your autoscaling nodes. You can use with Single Instance or Elastic Load Balancer.